# Conflicting shortcuts between IntelliJ IDEA and OSX

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, shortcut

There are quite a few conflicting shortcuts between IntelliJ IDEA and OSX. For example, [ctrl + arrow keys] to navigate between files and tool windows in IntelliJ IDEA.

Is there a way to prioritise shortcuts from IntelliJ IDEA over OSX?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised to see this is still an issue nowadays. @BARJ, did you find a way to do this?